# probability of events after a number of tries

Tags: probability

Suppose a player is playing a game and killing a monster, and the likelihood of a monster dropping an item is given by some probability p.  The player would like to know the probability of getting $\bf{exactly}$ n of these drops in m kills.

My thought process is this:

If the monster has a probability of dropping an item as p, then the probability of it happening n times in m kills can be visualized by some m-dimensional vector, whose entries can be filled with n checkmarks and (m-n) X's, where the checkmarks mean that the drop has been attained on that kill.  So a 30-vector whose 1st and 30th entries are checkmarks and all other entries are X's correspond to the player receiving a drop on the 1st and 30th kills and nothing on the other kills.

To describe this mathematically, I reason that the probability of any given vector configuration is given by $$(1-p)^{m-n}p^n$$  However, the checkmarks can be rearranged in any order, so the expression becomes $$\frac{(1-p)^{m-n}p^nm!}{(m-n)!}$$

I feel as though somehow this is wrong.  Hopefully I am making my thought process clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are super close. What you are looking for is the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution), which you have very nearly constructed perfectly. You're just missing an $n!$ in the denominator. Let N be the number of items dropped in m kills.

$P(N = n) = \binom{m}{n}p^n(1-p)^{m-n} ,\ \ n = 0,1,2,...m$

Where $\binom{m}{n}$ is the binomial coefficient.

$\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m!}{n!(m-n)!}$

Comment: I think I get it.  The 1/n! factor takes care of any redundancies arising from the  swapping of the checkmarks once they're in place?

Comment: Exactly! Without it you will have redundancies.